# reading a file to array of strings

Tags: c

I'm new to C and just  learning about malloc and realloc and help from the community in understanding how to do this. I have a file with paragraphs that I need to read line by line and store the lines in array o strings while creating the arrays dynamically.

Inillially the MAX number of lines to store is 10 if this is not sufficient we use realloc to double the memory and print a message indicating that we reallocated memory. So far this is what I have and need help to finish

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  char* p = malloc(10* sizeof(char));
  while(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin)
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C: Using malloc and realloc to double the initial memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24905608/c-using-malloc-and-realloc-to-double-the-initial-memory)

Answer (score 0):

`while(buffer, ...` does nothing, use `fgets`:

data.txt:

```
one
two
three
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_LEN 32

extern char *strdup(const char *);

int main(void)
{
    char **arr = NULL;
    char buf[BUF_LEN];
    size_t i, n = 0;
    FILE *f;

    f = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (fgets(buf, BUF_LEN, f)) {
        arr = realloc(arr, sizeof(*arr) * (n + 1));
        if (arr == NULL) {
            perror("realloc");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        arr[n] = strdup(buf);
        if (arr[n++] == NULL) {
            perror("strdup");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s", arr[i]);
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said and you do need array of strings. Come to think of it, a string is a sequence/array of characters, right? So you need array of array of characters.

Now, a `char *` is capable of pointing to a character and indirectly to the subsequent characters, if there are any. This is what we call as a string, and here's how we have one:

```
char * astring = malloc( 256 * sizeof * astring );
// astring holds an adress pointing to a memory location
// which has the capacity of 256 *astring s

// astring is a string tha can hold 255 characters
// with the full-stop '\0' at the end
```

Now you want 10 of such, 10 of `char *`s. `char **` will be able to point at them, just like `char *` can at `char`s.

```
char ** lines = malloc( 10 * sizeof * lines );
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    lines[i] = malloc( 256 );
    // sizeof may be omittid for chars
```

If you are planning to increase 10, it's a good idea to store that inside a variable, double it when needed and reallocate accordingly.

```
int numlines = 10;
int linelength = 256;
char ** lines = malloc( numlines * sizeof * lines );
for( int linenr = 0; fgets( lines[linenr] = malloc( linelength ), linelength, yourfile ) != EOF; linenr++ ) {
    if ( linenr + 1 == numlines ) {
        numlines *= 2;
        lines = realloc( lines, numlines * sizeof * lines );
    }
}
```

Include necessary headers, fill in the gaps and make checks if the allocations and `fopen` succeeded, make sure 256 is enough, increase that if necessary. You may optionally make that adaptive as well, but that'll require more code.