# Read Text line by line and assign variables per line

Tags: c, file, variables, line

I have accomplished getting my c program to read text line by line. That was the easy part or at least in my perspective. What i need to do now is to assign variables per line. For Example the first line of the text file would be equal to the variable line1.

Or this

```
char line1 = (text from line one)
char line2 = (text from line two)
```

My code thus far:

```
    char line[1000] = ""; 

    FILE *ifp;

    ifp = fopen("Tree-B.txt", "r");
    if (ifp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fscanf(ifp, "%s", line) == 1)
    {
        printf("%s ", line);
    }
    printf("\n");
    fclose(ifp);

    return 0;
```

I have absolutely no idea how to do this.

Comment: You could use an array.

Comment: You need to allocate with `malloc()` or use an array `line[1000][1000]`, but this is limited to 1000 lines and 999 characters.

Comment: [reading a file to array of strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908603/reading-a-file-to-array-of-strings)

Comment: @Stargateur why 999 `chars` , why not `1000`?

Comment: `fscanf(ifp, "%s", line)` does not save spaces.  More useful for reading words than lines.  Could use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi 999 is the maximum width of characters to read and save.  After reading, a null character is appended, hence 1000 `char` needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array of pointer for that matter.

```
char line[1000] = "";  // assume each line has at most 999 chars (1 space for NUL character)
char *lines[1000] = { NULL }; // assume max number of lines is 1000
int idx = 0;
FILE *ifp;

ifp = fopen("q2.cpp", "r");
if (ifp == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file!\n");
    exit(1);
}

while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), ifp) != NULL)
{
    lines[idx] = strdup(line);
    printf("%s", lines[idx]);
    idx++;
}
```

Notes:

- This approach using `strdup` which is POSIX (not official C standard). However, you can put in a [publicly available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c) `strdup` function itself.
- `fgets` is preferred than `fscanf` so I changed it that way.
- 1000 limis are suggestive - you can/should change those constants to what would make more sense in the program itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LINES 1000
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 200

int main()
{
    char fileContents[MAX_LINES][MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    int lineCount = 0;

    FILE *ifp = fopen("Tree-B.txt", "r");
    if (ifp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fgets(fileContents[lineCount++], MAX_LINE_LENGTH, ifp) != NULL);
    fclose(ifp);

    printf("File Contents:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < lineCount-1; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s", fileContents[i]); // or fputs
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970698/using-malloc-for-allocation-of-multi-dimensional-arrays-with-different-row-lengt), if you wish to dynamically allocate memory for fileContents.